# Issue with Google Tag Manager implementation. "Uncaught TypeError: Wb.set is not a function"

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Recently I started having Issues with the Google Tag Manager.
I can't track it to a Tag or a Trigger (activated and deactivated individually to check).

The error started occurring this week (no updates were made to the system or template). I noticed when testing the implementation of a new Tag in GTM. That shortly worked but then this error message started showing in the console. Removing the new Tag didn't change the situation and since the code worked for a while (some 30minutes) I don't expect a direct relationship between the new tag and the error.

All I have is the console in the frontend that shows the following error message:
Uncaught TypeError: Wb.set is not a function
The error stems from this file:
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXXX

Wb is started as a Map just a few steps earlier:
Wb=new Map(Vb.h.F);
Wb.set("style",{ya:4});

The GTM Script is copied and pasted from the GTM-Admin without any change made to it and is included in the header.php file of the Wordpress template. I tried copying it again and replacing the script that was in the header.php previously but the result was the same.

If looking at the actual error message in the console helps, the issue can be seen on the following URL:
https://www.bindella.ch

Any help in solving this or at least pointer to where to go look for errors would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Given that the console shows a similar error for optimize, might it be that you run an experiment and that the experiment has an error (like addressing an element that does not actually exist)?

Comment: @EikePierstorff Didn't think of that. Thanks! As Google Optimize isn't used anymore on our platform the Tag needed to go. Didn't solve the issue but at least cleaned up out container and load a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Very interesting, and yes, you're right, the error in the minified code makes no sense:
[image]

Let's try something different. First, just export your GTM container (the workspace that is synced with prod/live) as a JSON file in Admin section.

Open the file, look for something like `set("style"` See if you can find that Wb. Well, don't expect it to be Wb. I guess GTM minifies the code. It may be some weird chat bot, or something like that. From there, you'll be able to find the tag or variable that causes the issue.

I didn't look too deep into it, but that part of code looks sophisticated enough to be a part of the core container code. Actually, we can check it right here, on SO cuz it uses GTM too, let's do that.

[image]

Yes, SO has identical code. Looks like it's indeed core GTM. Well, there's a tiny probability that when you built the prod library last time, GTM had an issue and it deployed an artefact.

Try making a new workspace, make a nonsensical change in it and publish it to production. See if it lets you publish. Then see if that fixes the issue.

Now, if it doesn't then the next thing I'd try is trying to re-importing the exported JSON, forcing GTM compare the import to what's there and find differences.

Now if that shows no issues, then I would make a brand new container, load the config in it and try replacing the gtm loading script to see if the error still happens. It sounds like you can do that. If you can't, look a plugin like redirector to redirect the request to a different container.

Still the error with the new container? How about if you load a completely empty container? Got any errors?

There's a very slim chance that your front-end deploys one of a few vars GTM uses too, thus conflicting with your GTM. But it's very unlikely. Why would you use something like google_tag_manager or google_tag_data in the global scope...

If nothing helps and only the empty container doesn't give errors, then... well, then make a list of all tags firing along that error and start disabling them one by one. Or use breakpoints to narrow it down to the tag/library that causes it.

Comment: I'm at a loss for words. Thanks a million for taking the time to go through this work.
Went through all your steps. Can't find any reference to the .set function in the JSON. But that's not unexpected after reading the rest of your message.
Cleaned up the container, redeployed. no change.
Created an empty container, deployed it: no change.
I guess there must be aconflict with another library that's in use on the site and it's not an issue with the container itself or the tags in it. Thanks a million for your help this far.

Comment: Oh, I was afraid the empty container would cause the issue. Well now you have to start switching off js libraries one by one. Just use the network request blocker in devtools drawer for this. Keep GTM on, and start disabling any third party libs you see loaded in Network. Maybe you're lucky and it's just a third party script that causes the conflict. But it does look like it's in your main codebase :( Oh, that's wordpress. Maybe just start switching off plugins until you find the offender?

Comment: Have deactivated all modules individually to see if the error keeps ocurring. And it does. I've now created new instances of the Map in the console of my seiteand SO and in SO I do get an Object "Map" while on my own site I get an Object "Object". Trying to find out which file of the theme (I assume it's in the very core of the theme) defines this object. Will keep you posted and thanks again for your help.

Comment: Nah, I think I found it. Map.js. The file overrides the native Map class. And does it poorly. Just find what loads it and you're good. I blocked Map.js on your site and started seeing GA hits and no GTM errors. Feels good to find the offender. It's a good rule to not override native functions. Especially in such a way that breaks native functionality. Is it the theme who loads it? Looks like it. It's in the page's source...

Comment: Yeah, just got there and figured out where in the theme the file is loaded. Mate, you are awesome! thank you very much. Let me know if there ever is anything I can do for you :-)

Comment: Tell us what the theme name is so that we would know never to use it

Comment: It's a theme that a previous agency custom made for us, so unless you use them (I doubt you would) you should be save :-)

Comment: Heh, well, keep in mind that there is probably a reason why they overrode that Map class. Removing the overridal will likely break something.